# how can I validate a composite component on blur?

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I have a composite component that contains two inputText components.
The composite component manages a bean containing two Integers.

```
class valueBean {
  private Integer valueA;
  private Integer valueB;
  //getters, setters.
}

<composite:interface componentType="valueBeanUI">
  <composite:attribute name="value">
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <h:inputText id="inputA"/>
  <h:inputText id="inputB"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

In my valueBeanUI I implement getConvertedValue and encodeBegin.

Everything works as expected - when I click submit the code in getConvertedValue is called and I can throw error messages if the conversion values if the user enters characters in the integer fields.

What I would like to do is be able to require a valid value in both fields, and show one error message if this condition is not met. I have this working when the user clicks submit, but I'd like to fire it on blur of either field (inputA or inputB). I cant figure out how to validate the backing component when either field blurs. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this? I dont want to submit the whole form - I'd like to do just this component via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `<f:ajax event="blur">` to the inputs.

```html
<h:inputText id="inputA">
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this inputB" render="messageForInputA messageForInputB" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="inputB">
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this inputA" render="messageForInputA messageForInputB" />
</h:inputText>
```

The `messageForInputA` should point to a `<h:message id="messageForInputA">`.

Comment: Should process= be execute= ? According to the facelets spec f:ajax doesnt have a process attribute.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Don't even need the backing component now - can get what I wanted with custom converters and validators.